# MySQLi num_rows returns 0

Tags: php, mysqli

Here's my code

```
$stmt = $conn->mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt = $conn->mysqli->prepare('SELECT Username, EmailVerified, Blocked FROM user WHERE Email = ? AND SLANumber = ? AND Password = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ssb', $_POST['EmailID'], $_POST['SLANumber'], $_POST['Password']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result->num_rows == 0){
    echo 'No rows found';
}
else{
    // Continue processing here
    .....
}
```

The code always echoes `No rows found`. A day or two before, it was working fine.

As expected, running the query directly gives the desired result.

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Why are you sending `$_POST['Password']` as a blob `b` instead of a string `s`?

Comment: @Michael: I read it in documentation on php.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`num_rows` is a property of `mysqli_stmt`, not of a result resource. So you should be doing:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();

// Also check strict comparison against int 0,
// to avoid incorrect equality with boolean FALSE
if($stmt->num_rows === 0){
    echo 'No rows found';
}
```

Comment: It is property of Result also. See http://in2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php.

Comment: Using $stmt->num_rows still returns 0.

Comment: Another problem, using `$row = $result->fetch_object();` in **else** block gives the error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs........`.

Comment: Sorry for my previous-to-previous comment. === is actually evaluating to false, since `echo $result->num_rows;` prints nothing. That means problem is still there.

Comment: @kush.impetus Then your query failed, and `$result` is FALSE instead of a valid result resource.

Comment: @kush.impetus you are right. This doesn't work. You either need to do `$stmt->store_result();` so that `$stmt->num_rows` is not 0, or you need to call `$result->num_rows`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192229/num-rows-get-result-vs-store-result/40192435#40192435

Comment: @Adam You have changed the answer. The code is now correct, but the explanation makes no sense. It never made any sense, because the answer was wrong, but when you edited you could at least change the explanation. However, I think that in this case you should **not** edit, but write your own answer. I will roll it back. You can post your own answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use store_result and get_result together in the same statement.

Use store_result method with "num_rows", "bind_result" and "fetch".

For get_result method, use "affected_rows" and "fetch_array". You can still use the "num_rows" property in the income get_result method as shown below.

```
$stmt->execute();
// $stmt->store_result();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if(result->num_rows == 0){
  ...
}
```

OR

```
$stmt->execute();
// $stmt->store_result();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($stmt->affected_rows == 0){
  ...
}
```

Comment: `affected_rows` is misleading. It is not the same as `num_rows`

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem remove this line:

```
$stmt->store_result();
```

The problem is that you used two methods which are in conflict with each other.

```
$stmt->store_result();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Both of these methods fetch the results. `store_result()` fetches the results internally and stores them in the statement object. I would advise to avoid this method whenever possible. It is difficult to use. `get_result()` fetches the results and saves them in a separate object. Once the results are fetched from MySQL, they cannot be fetched again. **Use only one of these methods at a time**.

In your case you first stored the results in `mysqli_stmt` and then fetched an empty result set into `$result`. `$result` will contain 0 rows, because all of the records have already been stored in the statement. To get the number of rows stored there use `$stmt->num_rows`.

Both `mysqli_stmt` and `mysqli_result` classes have the `num_rows` property. The key is to use the appropriate one.