# how to count multiple arrays returned from query,

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this query. The where clause is an array and it works fine.

I need to count the number of separate arrays returned, is there any way to do this,

output is:
Array ( [0] => 64 ) Array ( [0] => 64 [1] => 65 ).

```
     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   $message = explode(",", $message_arrayME);
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   $i = 0;
   foreach ($message as $key => $value) { 
   $i++; // increment $i by one each loop pass 
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////


   $q = mysqli_prepare($conn, ' SELECT member_id FROM members WHERE message_id=? ');
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q, 's', $value);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($q);
   mysqli_stmt_store_result($q);
   //$friendNumResult =mysqli_stmt_num_rows($q);    
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($q, $memberId);


   while($row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($q)):

   $messageArrayNumResult[] = '
   '.$memberId.' 
   ';
   endwhile; mysqli_stmt_close($q);

   //echo $memberIdArray;
   //$friendCount = count($memberIdArray);
   //print_r($memberId);

    $messageArray2 = implode(",",$messageArrayNumResult);

    print_r( $messageArrayNumResult);

   }
```

Fixed it:

```
    $friendNum1 = implode(",", $messageArrayNumResult);
    $friendNum2 = explode(",", $friendNum1 );
    $friendCount= count($friendNum2);}
```

Silly me :)

Comment: Could you please state your question more clearly? It sounds like the generation of your arrays works fine, but do you want the total amount of items in all arrays or just the number of arrays made?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you take your data out you can count it in a few different ways... If you already have an array of users that is one users "friend list" you can just count that array... EX:

```
$num_friends = count($friend_array);
```

Also depending on how you are taking data out of your database if each friend connection is in a row, and not one row with all friends seperated by something you use to explode you can just count the number of rows. Ex:

```
 $q = mysqli_prepare($conn, ' SELECT member_id FROM members WHERE message_id=? ');
$num_friends = $q->get_result();
```

Explination of the second row [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722295/mysqli-num-rows-returns-0).